# Does any of you know how to mask a URL in php ? or related to Javascriptor Ajax?

Tags: php, url, mask

Does any of you know how to mask a URL in php?? Like the one you see in free URL redirectional services (http://www.shorturl.com)

I mean I have a url like http://www.my-server.com/

which will redirect me to http://www.some-other-server.com/abc.php

But I want the URL in the address bar of my browser to show only this URL

http://www.my-server.com/

Is this possible??

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Don't short URLs from ShortURL.com do redirects and reflect the change in the address bar?

Comment: @David Dorward: oops, I must've been half asleep when I posted that response :P

Answer (score 1):

Use url-rewriting via e.g. [mod_rewrite](http://www.modrewrite.de/).

Edit: won't work cross server, I forgot.
Then link your domain to the other server using the DNS-entry.

Comment: Linking via DNS won't work if the other server uses virtual name hosting (which is very likely unless it is a huge site). It also won't let you change the local part of the URI, so http://www.my-server.com/ would go to http://www.some-other-server.com/ instead of http://www.some-other-server.com/abc.php

Comment: What the heck? Why shouldn't he be able to add his domain to the other server/webspace? Almost every provider supports that.

Comment: Oh, you meant an normal A record rather than a redirect? The question implied the other domain wasn't under the control of the OP (given the discussion of shorturl services being similar to what was wanted) so virtual name hosting would fail if you tried that.

Answer (score 0):

The two options are to:

1. Copy the data from the destination URL to the URL you want it to appear on
2. [Frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html) — which have horrible drawbacks and don't stop a user finding out what the real URI is in a click or two.

Trying to disguise a URI while letting a user access it is Not A Good Idea (TM).

Comment: Do you really think he want's to disguise the URI? More than 1 Domain seems more likely.

Comment: He said "But I want the URL in the address bar of my browser to show only this URL" — so, yes, I do. The motivations might not be to deceive, but that task is the same.

Comment: Maybe he only wants the abc.php as index for the second domain. He didn't state that the whole site should only show this domain.

Answer (score 0):

You could run nginx or apache in reverse proxy mode on `www.my-server.com`, and configure it to forward requests to `www.my-other-domain.com`. If both domains are hosted on the same network, it'll be tolerable. If they are hosted on different networks, the bandwidth waste might be awful.